# Java shorthand for using duplicate code

Tags: java, java-8

I want to know if I can write this code shorter in Java 8,
let's assume that I need to add additional `set` methods.

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(900000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(900000);
...
```

Comment: No, there is no with() or using() construct like in other languages, if that's what you were thinking about.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem here.

Comment: @JoeC the repetition of the urlConnection variable, to call multiple methods on the same object. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#calling-multiple-methods-on-an-object-instance-with for what Kotlin allows doing, for example.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Nope, can't do that in Java.  Sorry.

Comment: Give your variable a shorter name?

Comment: @JBNizet - Ok understand , thanks

Comment: What is so gosh-darned important about it being shorter?

Comment: Have a look at [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) - that's the closest thing to what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

There's no syntax in Java that allows for what you want, though you could mimic it if you had this method in your toolbox:

```
public static <T> T with(T instance, Consumer<? super T> action) {
    action.accept(instance);
    return instance;
}
```

Your example would now become:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = with(
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy),
    u -> {
        u.setConnectTimeout(900000);
        u.setReadTimeout(900000);
    });
```

But honestly, I see no much gaining...

Comment: @Karl The lines of the static method do not count :) That method is supposed to be in your own library of nasty hacks... And you could format the code that uses the method so that it has 4 lines (if you count the closing brace and parenthesis). The final code would have much less characters, though... But as I said in the answer, I see no much gaining. I wrote this answer mainly for fun...

Comment: Understood. Actually, I really like this example. My adoption of Java Lambda has been slow and I'm happy to see more non-data examples.